# Is there anyone success with ROS Linux + LabVIEW RT?

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

My plan is having ROS nodes on Linux and on LabVIEW RT (MyRIO) work together with ROS master running on Linux. Currently, I am using the ROS LabVIEW library from Tufts university. I tested and proved success to be able run roscore on Linux communicating with ros node on LabVIEW PC (non-RT). But I don't have success communication between roscore runs on Linux and ros node runs on MyRIO (RT). If anyone know how to make this work please have me with instructions.

Thank you in advance.

Edit 1:
The subscriber in LabVIEW RT cannot receive message from publisher in Linux (ROS master run on Linux). I also tried with ROS master run on PC, publisher run on LabVIEW PC and subscriber run on LabVIEW RT. The subscriber in this case does not receive message from publisher either. But if I ran the ROS master in LabVIEW RT, I can receive message from publisher run on LabVIEW PC.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/239586/is-there-anyone-success-with-ros-linux-+-labview-rt?/) by [Thang Nguyen](https://answers.ros.org/users/25138/thang-nguyen/) on ROS Answers with karma: 93 on 2016-07-15

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2016-07-15**:\

> But I don't have success communication between roscore runs on Linux and ros node runs on MyRIO (RT)

Could you add what doesn't work in this case?

**Comment by [Thang Nguyen](https://answers.ros.org/users/25138/thang-nguyen/) on 2016-07-15**:
@gvdhoorn: I added detail in my question.

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2016-07-15**:
If this was two Linux PCs, I would guess this is a configuration issue. What are the values of `ROS_HOSTNAME`, `ROS_IP` and `ROS_MASTER_URI` on all machines involved?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The current update allows me to communicate successful between Linux host and MyRIO.

---

Originally posted by [Thang Nguyen](https://answers.ros.org/users/25138/thang-nguyen/) with karma: 93 on 2016-09-20

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Raphaelaasilva](https://answers.ros.org/users/28659/raphaelaasilva/) on 2016-12-05**:
How did you do the communication between ROS/linux and myRIO? Can you share step by step?

**Comment by [Thang Nguyen](https://answers.ros.org/users/25138/thang-nguyen/) on 2016-12-05**:
If you download the code, there is a tutorial in the example shows you step by step how to do that.
Regards

**Comment by [Raphaelaasilva](https://answers.ros.org/users/28659/raphaelaasilva/) on 2016-12-05**:
Sorry, what code? which tutorial? can you send the links? I'm trying to follow some infos I've found on internet here and there and in the tool kit from Tufts university and I communicate successfully ROS/linux and labview/PC, however myRIO not yet.

**Comment by [Muda](https://answers.ros.org/users/31121/muda/) on 2017-07-12**:
Hey, I know this is an old post, but I ned to conenct ROS to myRIO wirelessly.

Any chance you can share that code that you mentioned in your comment???????

Thanks in advance.